# Astronomy questions I wondered for hours

Tags: big-bang-theory, early-universe

I read a question posted by a community member in my community that shocked me, I think it contains some pretty cool astronomy questions that I cant wait for you scientists to answer. I am asking this from stack exchange, because this is where all the real scientists are , and I want to see the truth , a real explanation , brief but simple.

I wont copy the exact question details because it will make it duplicate, but the question is posted here, please take time to read the details and explain it to me it is posted here- 
http://srilanka.answercup.com/question/215/how-can-i-convince-my-atheist-friend-that-god-exists/

I am fascinated by his explanation, I cant wait for the astronomy community to tell me the answers this guy is asking.

Ok this is the question I am pasting it here after being requested by a member on the comment section-

His tite is - 
How can i convince my atheist friend that God exists???

Apparently he seems to be religious person, who has some points to make.
This is the description of his question-

> There is this friend that I have who believes in science and doesnt believe in religion. We have had many arguements, and it raises many interesting questions. I am posting this to see Answercup users opinion on it. If scientists say that Big bang is proven I have some simple questions . What happened before the big bang according to these scientists? And this big bang theory came from scientists thinking that the universe expands so if we reverse the time, it will do the opposite and come to one single point....but then if it did come from a point, I found that the expansion is INCREASING which is weird. How on earth can it be a blast , because obv like any blast it should decreases and come to a hault , here instead of the universe expansion decelerating its actually accelerating. How can these so called scientists tell something is right when common sense which can be understood by primary school children shows clearly that they are wrong ??? Plus how can you seriously get a blast from empty space ? If scientist says thats the beginning of time.

With his question, I remembered watching the vedio "Does god exist" on Discovery channel by stephen hawking. His explanations wasnt complete and he bragged about how there is no need for god, but his explanation never explained many parts. And then there are scientists who gives the excuse laws of physics break at the point of the big bang so we can't explain. So this brought my mind a new question, if scientists still cant understand what has happens in the big bang , how can they tell that God doesnt exist, and stuff like that and make them appear as facts, if they knew the physics at the big bang and talked then its fine, but here they are talking without even knowing those.

Source: http://srilanka.answercup.com/question/215/how-can-i-convince-my-atheist-friend-that-god-exists/

Comment: Please copy the question here. Links can die, and thus render this question unusable for future readers.

Comment: ok sure. I was going to copy it but then I was thinking if its a bad idea to copy someone elses question to another place. Lemme do that real fast

Comment: @Envite done. Please check it now. I dont think I will be able to sleep without an answer  *excited for explanations*

Comment: I have to note my opinion, out of all the three questions he has asked , I find the second one ironic, where the same people tell its a big bang  and then they also tell expansion is acceleration. Which is ironic atleast to me (a layman).

Comment: But also after thinking for a long time this is what I have come to understand, and i want to share it , yes blasts expansion in like earth and all decelerate with time because there is maybe friction, but yes in a big bang the outer must have been a vacuum so obviously no friction, but in this case there wont be resistance force so it will be constant speed isnt it ???? or constant acceleration?? but now can it be increasing speed or acceleration? Thats the point.

Comment: This site is about science, not religion.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about religion, not science.

Comment: This is a layman asking a question about science. I just pasted his question because you asked me to @Envite , the guy who asked this question was asking about religion, but Im asking questions after reading his question. Its not his question that im asking but rather an explanation for his scientific facts.

Comment: Im sorry @Envite , it seemed to be a religious question because i copied it, but my questions what i wonder originated from his explanation, but not his specific question on how to convince. I think i should not have copied it here, changed the meaning of my question :/

Comment: You should watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XBr4GkRnY04) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q3MWRvLndzs) first.

Comment: @Yashbhatt wow thank you :) these are really nice vedios :) im happy that i learnt somethings today about the big bang :)

Comment: @Tharindu You should watch more videos by minutephysics and Veritasium like common physics misconceptions etc.

Comment: Like it's been said, @Tharindu. there are some religious implications of this question. That said, I would refer you to some of the religion-based Stack Exchanges, or the Philosophy Stack Exchange.

Comment: Hi, As currently worded this is a very religion heavy question which isn't really fit for our site. If you have a specific astronomy related question please feel free to ask it in a new question. Thanks, Rhys

Answer (score 6):

If you think on Big Bang as an explosion **IN** space, you are plain wrong. It was not. It was an explosion **OF** space itself. And time, for that matter.

> What happened before the big bang according to these scientists?

Common misconception. There is no "before". Time starts at Big Bang.

> How on earth can it be a blast , because obv like any blast it should decreases and come to a hault , here instead of the universe expansion decelerating its actually accelerating.

Common misconception. It is not a blast in space. It is the space itself expanding, and there is no outside from where to see it decelerate and stop.

> how can they tell that God doesnt exist, and stuff like that and make them appear as facts, if they knew the physics at the big bang and talked then its fine, but here they are talking without even knowing those.

God is not part of Science, this question is out of topic here.

Comment: If there was no befor the bang ? Where did the material come from??? I mean there should be something to cause it right? now I can expect a big bang to happen in the middle of my room in empty space???

Comment: Whether it was an explosion in space or it was the space that exploded. It doesnt matter, its something that expanded. Do you agree that space is expanding at a faster and faster accelerating rate??? Do you have an explaination for me on that ?

Comment: No, it can not happen in the middle of your room in empty space, because Big Bang did not happen in empty space. It was the start of all space. There were no empty space around, no void around, because there is no around. The material did not come from any place. The Big Bang was the origin of all material and energy. And no, nothing could cause it, because any cause must be before its consequence, and Big Bang has no before. It is the start of time.

Comment: Do scientist have any proof for the big bang ? That it was what happened and nothing else could have been the reason? Any proof I can refer to ?

Comment: Proof of big bang: that is a different question. Please ask it separatedly. Or better, use the Search engine of this site.

Comment: Do you accept that the expansion is increasing at an accelerating rate??? What causes the expansion to accelerate?

Comment: Accelerated expansion: This is also a question that has been asked before. Please use the search button.

Comment: Ok :) Thank you @Envite for devoting your time for this question.